# Calendar.app can't add events or calendars

Tags: macos, calendar

This is on my Wife's Intel MBA with Ventura 13.2.1. She had a problem importing an ics file from an online source that works fine on my MBP.

Upon closer investigation her Calendar (iCloud) was completely empty of events and if I tried to add the event from the ics file I got an odd error message:

[image: Import failed to save]

Investigating further it seems that if I try to add an event to the calendar, nothing happens, literally. Selecting *File → New Event* or clicking on the "+" button there is no response from calendar.app.

Then I notice (duh) that there are no calendars listed in the sidebar, So I try *File → New Calendar*  and get this:

[image: This calendar can't be added]

Now I go into Calendar's Accounts Preference pane and remove and then try and re add her iCloud calendar (there are two Gmail accounts there but they are disabled there, and calendars are turned off in those accounts in System Settings) but when I try and log in it says her iCloud account is locked for security reasons... Grrr...

I log into her iCloud account, reset the account password and try again. Having verified that calendars are turned on in *System Settings → iCloud* and that her calendar app is working just fine on her iPhone, *none of her calendars show up in the sidebar* (and I **still** can't add an event). Which makes some kind of sense as there are no actual calendars to display besides the default calendar that is displayed when there aren't any calendars.

There was one lone Calendar.app preference file in the `~/Library/Preferences` folder which I deleted with no detectable change in behavior and I did not find any other preference/settings files anywhere else in `~/Library` or `/Library`.

I am a loss as to why the calendars that display fine on my wife's iPhone are MIA on her MBA

Comment: Out of curiosity...If you disable *all* syncing of the Calendar on the iPhone, can you create a new calendar event in iCloud (web interface)?

Comment: If I disable syncing on the phone and I lose even **ONE** calendar entry for my wife y'all will be holding the first AD online funeral for a member ;-) So while I see the possible utility of doing that, I would rather keep the solution to just the Mac, on which the calendar is not working and leave the working iOS calendar alone.

Comment: Backup anything important (for example, the calendar events) and then wipe the hard drive and reset it to factory settings. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212749.

Comment: What type of user account does your wife have on this computer? Admin, or something else?

Comment: It's an admin account. And wiping the hard drive and starting from scratch is a non-starter, she can't do without the Mac and the calendar is *fine* on the phone so getting it working on the Mac would be helpful, but she is used to doing calendar things exclusively on the phone. And these days with the SSV reinstalling the OS doesn't do what it used to.

Comment: ...Aaaaaaand it just started working again for no particular reason. I went to open it to do some more troubleshooting and the calendar was there, strange. Thx all for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same here; could not add a calendar either, a read-only account.  On my machine, the directory `~/Library/Calendars` was owned by root. That is not correct, looking at another macOS system. Fixed  it with:

`sudo chown -R <username>:staff ~/Library/Calendars`

I'm not sure how this happened, it's a relatively new machine, maybe the transfer of data and settings from the old machine failed somewhere.

**Update**: When I had fixed it with the command line, my Gmail address calendars were back quickly, but not the iCloud ones. I got an unexpected error (sic!):

```
Your calendar couldn't be refreshed:
There was an unexpected error with the request (domain DAErrorDomain / error 6).
```

I needed to sign out and in of my AppleID to fix that.